# WPF application not displayed in Task Manager

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My WPF application does not shown in windows task manager application tab but it shown in taskbar and task manager processes tab. 
How do I fix this problem? or what is the problem?

Comment: Does your application maybe have a zero length window title?

Comment: Thanks @fmunkert! I have forgotten to set `Windows title`.

Comment: Hi. I have the same issue. App is not showing in task manager. Window `Title` is okay, as well as `WindowStyle`. App is running perfectly. But simply does not appear in task manager. I'm running the app from bin/debug. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the `WindowStyle="ToolWindow"`?

If so then that's why it's not showing in the Applications tab of Task Manager.

If you were using that style so that you could get rid of the minimize/maximize buttons, then an alternative way is to restyle the Window template.

Or you could use some of the ideas here to change the style of the Window without using a ToolWindow style.

- [How do I remove minimize and maximize from a resizable window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339620/how-do-i-remove-minimize-and-maximize-from-a-resizable-window-in-wpf)