# How to add a button to a window title?

Tags: wpf, titlebar

I want to add to the title of a mainwindow in my WPF application a button.
I would also like to remove re minimize and exit buttons from there.
How can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK You'll need a custom chrome to add buttons to the window chrome. Something like [Mahapps Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#customisation)

Comment: are you sure it can't be done? I almost sure three is a way to add this button or even add a label or some shapes...

Comment: Well the default window chrome comes from the native windows API. Your options are either deal with them directly to inject what you need or just use a Chrome helper tool to create a custom chrome and accordingly add whatever controls you need there. I did not say it "cannot" be done, Just that no out of the box WPF only way of doing it without some third-party helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably these links will help you:

Remove close button:
[How to hide close button in WPF window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743906/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window)

Remove min/max buttons
[How do I remove minimize and maximize from a resizable window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339620/how-do-i-remove-minimize-and-maximize-from-a-resizable-window-in-wpf)

To add a button to the window title you can use WPF customizable window control:
http://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/

Hope it will help you!