# How to Disable restore box of windows form when it is in maximized condition?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I disable the restore button in the control box of a windows form in c#. i need to make the form in maximized condition when it loads. is it possible? even the maximize box property is false, the restore box is shown automatically on the screen.

Comment: Set the ControlBox property MaximizeBox and MinimizedBox to false.? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox.aspx

Comment: If you set `MaximizeBox` to false, the restore box will not appear. If that does not work for you, you will need to update your question with more information, like a [simple, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

So from my comment you do this:

```
// Define the border style of the form to a dialog box.
form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

// Set the MaximizeBox to false to remove the maximize box.
form1.MaximizeBox = false;

// Set the MinimizeBox to false to remove the minimize box.
form1.MinimizeBox = false;
```

This is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximizebox.aspx)

To maximize your form you simply do this:

```
form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Again this can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx)

Comment: i have set the form properties as given below FormBorderStyle = FixedDialog; MaximizeBox = false;
MinimizeBox = false; windowsState = Maximized; but its not working. the restore key appeared automatically.

Comment: @Roys - You will have to give me more than that for me to help you, What are you doing to get this problem? Where have you used this code? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question:
[How do I remove minimize and maximize from a resizable window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339620/how-do-i-remove-minimize-and-maximize-from-a-resizable-window-in-wpf)

The first and most upvoted answer doesn't belong to WPF only. So it should also work with a Winforms application.

Comment: There's just no point in using pinvoke when you can simply set the properties in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ResizeMode = CanMinimize` and `windowState = Maximized` in the property panel.